# Meteor.js how to get the userId inside an onStop event?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm runing this on my meteor.js server:

```
Meteor.publish('games', function(){

    this.onStop(function() {
        Meteor.call('leaveQueue');
    });

    return Games.find({ player: this.userId })
});
```

When the user stops the subscription, it calls this function that is on methods.js:

```
Meteor.methods({

    leaveQueue:function(){
        console.log(this.userId);
    }

});
```

It logs null as the userId..
Now if I call it from the frontend using Meteor.call('leaveQueue') on the console, it logs the user id correctly.

I even tried console.log(Meteor.userId) and console.log(Meteor.userId()), all null.

What could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Meteor allows you to call a Method from another Method on the server side, and maintain the proper context (so `userId`, `connection`, etc. are all taken from the original Method call). This is not the case when calling a Method from a publish function however. When you make your `Meteor.call` from within your publication, the called Method tries to extract `userId` details from the current DDP connection (by looking at the internal `DDP._CurrentInvocation`). These details don't exist, so the called Method is unable to preserve them (for more information, see the [ddp-server/livedata_server.js](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/a912eed990002824b3407ffa49cb4b9393539fe0/packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js#L1598) source).

That being said, you are able to get the current `userId` in the `onStop` callback of your publication:

```
Meteor.publish('games', function games() {
  this.onStop(() => {
    // This will log the proper userId
    console.log(this.userId);
  });
  return Games.find({ player: this.userId })
});
```

I'd suggest running your Method code with the `userId` in the `onStop` callback by calling a utility function instead of a Meteor Method. If you want to avoid duplicating code, you could extract the common code of your Method out into a utility function, and leverage it in both places. For example:

```
// Stored in a utility file somewhere
function doSomethingCommon(userId) {
  // Do something ...
}

Meteor.methods({
  leaveQueue() {
    doSomethingCommon(Meteor.userId());
  }
});

Meteor.publish('games', function games() {
  this.onStop(() => {
    doSomethingCommon(this.userId);
  });
  return Games.find({ player: this.userId })
});
```